# Static Library - Static library using own Qt .so file

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt4

I want to compile a static library for Qt Project version 4.7.4. But whatever I'm changing in `.pro` file it will not affecting on changes. I want change for example `libQt5Gui.so` to point on `/opt/vendor/extlib/libQt5Gui.so`, but I'm not lucky at moment:

I'm copying files from Ubuntu to virtual machine on cleanly installed Xubuntu 13.04.

When I'm using `ldd` command it returns:

```
marin@host:~/some_dir/test$ ldd ./Project02
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76e7000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xb70c6000)
libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0xb708a000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6fa0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6f83000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6dd0000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6db4000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb6d64000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6c63000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb6b2c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6ae9000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76e8000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb6ae2000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb6aa1000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb6a7e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6a79000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb6a75000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb6a6e000)
```

So you, i didn't figure why is:

```
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

My `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Project02
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    editorplain.cpp \
    logssession.cpp \
    createcontroller.cpp \
    createmodel.cpp \
    createview.cpp \
    envview.cpp \
    properties.cpp \
    debugsettings.cpp \
    serverconf.cpp \
    frameworkview.cpp \
    helpergen.cpp \
    offlineserver.cpp \
    cssproperty.cpp \
    regex.cpp \
    formgen.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    editorplain.h \
    logssession.h \
    createcontroller.h \
    createmodel.h \
    createview.h \
    envview.h \
    properties.h \
    debugsettings.h \
    serverconf.h \
    frameworkview.h \
    helpergen.h \
    offlineserver.h \
    cssproperty.h \
    regex.h \
    formgen.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    editorplain.ui \
    logssession.ui \
    createcontroller.ui \
    createmodel.ui \
    createview.ui \
    envview.ui \
    properties.ui \
    debugsettings.ui \
    serverconf.ui \
    frameworkview.ui \
    helpergen.ui \
    offlineserver.ui \
    cssproperty.ui \
    regex.ui \
    formgen.ui

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc

CONFIG += staticlib

LIBS += -L$$PWD/extstaticlibs/ -lFoobar
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/extstaticlibs
```

In `.pro` file i've added only:

```
CONFIG += staticlib

LIBS += -L$$PWD/extstaticlibs/ -lFoobar
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/extstaticlibs
```

On $$PWD/extstaticlibs there is copy files of `libQt5Gui.so.5`.

So, have to make static library works without dynamic shared `.so` Qt scripts as standalone app? Thank you!

Comment: To link against static Qt libraries you need to build a static version of Qt (run `./configure --help` in Qt source directory to see how to do it). And why are you referring at 4.7.4 version, while you are obviously using Qt5?

Comment: I'm working on Qt5, but some widgets are worked in version 4 so .pro file is there. Please give me some really example that really works. I've found a YT link for static comple so using `g++ --static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question. Using `g++ --static --release` and compile with minigw under Windows machine would solved this problem. A recommended version is use shared library of Qt due to better support for Qt libraries.

I solved this problem in Unix too, using DEB package and addding a shared library `libqt5gui` and `libqt5core`.

For static library i'm not solved fully yet, so I will not recommend using this solution due to incompatible `gcc` version and c++ compiler on other platforms. It will prevents for screwing up of compile codes.